# I am not able to convert DD/MM/YY format to MMMM/YY in google sheet

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, data-cleaning

I m trying to clean my datasheet in google sheets and I want only month and year from DD/MM/YY format but I can't format it with date &time in format number.

Comment: Then your data is not truly dates. They are stored as text. Please share a sample gs so that we can check it.

Comment: What is the output of: `=ISDATE(A1)`? When this is TRUE you have a valid date, and formatting should be possible. When this is FALSE, you do not have a valid date.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output,

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d{2})", "20$3-$2-01")*1
```

[image]

Comment: When I enter `'12/24/22` in A1 (Note the single quote) the formatting of Google sheets with this date still seems to work...

Comment: @Luuk, it depends on your locale. If your are in 'FR' you will not be able to get a date in that situation. It is necessary to get a sample to solve that problem.

Comment: I need more ☕.  I did add `0` to the date (in B1: =0+A1), and formatted the value in B1. Then doing some other things, and forgot about this addition .   Sorry for this!